# What coding is used in this string?

Tags: string, email

My app is downloading eMails from a POP3 server. But it receives "strange" subject lines. I see there is a pattern of coding in there. But what exactly is that coding? What do I google for if I want cover the parsing of lines like that?

```
=?utf-8?Q?HMS=20will=20no=20longer=20provide=20Netbiter=20SIM=2Dcards?=
```

The eMail header is:

`Subject: =?utf-8?Q?HMS=20will=20no=20longer=20provide=20Netbiter=20SIM=2Dcards?=`

So I know it's coded by the sender. Also this is just one of many header lines, which all seem to be valid. The subject is obviously **HMS will no longer provide Netbiter SIM-cards** after you replace "=20" with spaces and all the other stuff. The eMail is just a notification from a supplier.

---

**Found it myself:** [RFC 2047][1]

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember exactly but i have experienced a issue like this before. If the subject is greater than some length of character (which i think is 75 chars) then subject will not be parsed properly.

This used to be a problem in codeIgniter (I don't use it now, so don't know the current status of this issue)

To resolve this issue you might have to change your email config.

There might be other reasons for this issue but i think this is because you have more characters in your subject.

Comment: Actually this is more like the raw download. There are eMails with plain text subjects and this one. It's an html eMail.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. So, this response may not be correct. 

You retrieve an email through the server. What you see or view in the browser is actually the response given to your browser from the server.
If the server or the engine or the API that parses the email is setup correctly then you will not see this error.

What I think you should understand is the encoded words should not be more than some number of characters( which i think is 75). If you are using an app like MS outlook or other then it is not Application fault. 
Also read about RFC2047. It might help.

Comment: Well at least we came to the same page/document. I found it too in the RFC 2047.

Comment: Also note that if you think the mails you are receiving is a spam then  the spammer might have used RFC2047.

I may not be clear in my comment because i don't know how to express my writing correctly. I might point to something useless or something that you might not understand. My English is up and down (lol). Sorry for that.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm not native English myself.